# Filtering data for grouped bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to filter my dataset to just one year (1979) to display in my grouped bar chart which is based off Mike Bostock's example.

Sample:

```
1979,Colorectal cancer,20378,19178
1979,Lung cancer,63925,21093
1979,Prostate cancer,6403,43923
1979,Acute myocardial infarction,161723,45470
1979,Cerebrovascular diseases,35719,29415
1979,All stroke,31951,27062
1979,Unintentional injuries,316585,98160
1979,Suicides,89943,27078
1980,Colorectal cancer,20065,18100
1980,Lung cancer,65650,21993
1980,Prostate cancer,6180,43938
1980,Acute myocardial infarction,155525,44623
1980,Cerebrovascular diseases,32367,28014
1980,All stroke,28780,25437
1980,Unintentional injuries,292815,95622
...
```

In an earlier experiment I tried a piece of my dataset without Year and it was working fine.

```
Colorectal cancer,20378,19178
Lung cancer,63925,21093
Prostate cancer,6403,43923
Acute myocardial infarction,161723,45470
Cerebrovascular diseases,35719,29415
All stroke,31951,27062
Unintentional injuries,316585,98160
1979,Suicides,89943,27078
```

It seems using my full dataset with the addition of Year is causing some problems in my code and I can't seem to pinpoint where things are broken. If anyone could help it'd be fantastic.

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyab4kcf/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The year key is a) all upper chars and b) a string. Change your filter statement according:

```
var yearData = data.filter(function(element) {return element.YEAR == "1979"});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/vyab4kcf/4/)